# I need to create a regular expression for an input which will take a 1, 2, 3 or 4 digit input - but won't accept just "0"

Tags: javascript, regex

At the moment this is what my regex looks like:

```
/^\d{1,4}$/
```

It does 95% of what I want. It accepts strings like:

```
1234
2
21
9999
0100
```

But it also accepts strings like:

```
0
00
000
0000
```

I don't want it to do this. How do I stop it while keeping the behaviour I do want?

Comment: Did you check the answers?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a bit of a simpler one:

```
^(?!^0+$)\d{1,4}
```

And a working regex101 example:
https://regex101.com/r/eCmCKn/1

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regular expression which uses a negative lookahead.

```
(?!(?:0|^|)0{1,4}$)\d{1,4}
```

Here is a running example of this regex:

```js
var array = [
  "1234",
  "2",
  "21",
  "9999",
  "0100",
  "0",
  "00",
  "000",
  "0000"
];
var regex = /(?!(?:0|^|)0{1,4}$)\d{1,4}/;

array.forEach(function(item) {
  var match = item.match(regex);
  console.log(item + ":", match ? match[0] : "no match");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect!

Comment: Seems a bit more complicated than it needs to be. ;)  Try this: `^(?!0{1,4}$)\d{1,4}$`

Comment: @JamesWilkins - this one is also a bit complicated. Check my answer :)

Comment: I saw yours, I was just reworking his (staying true to the layout), that's all. ;) Actually, I was going to post something similar and you beat me to it. :P ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
/(^0|^0[1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2}|^[1-9][0-9]{0,3})$/g
```

It basically takes care of the cases:
1) the case of 0
2) any number starting with one leading 0 
3) any number not starting with 0

Hope it helps!

Comment: Did you check the other answers before posting this one?

Comment: @Dekel - hey just saw them... I was working it out on my console, so did not check the other answers...

Comment: Got it. As you can see now, other answer that are much simpler than yours :)

Comment: Yes I see they are quite simpler, but I prefer not having negative look ahead, as a general practice, as the they may be heavier on performance, however i have not profiled this case, so they may actually be more efficient.  Thank you!